# Microsoft SSIS Toolbox explanation

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to find explanation of every single component in visual studio toolbox of SSIS project.

Maybe anyone from here know, where I can find description of toolbox components ?

Answer (score 0):

To find the explanation of every single component in visual studio toolbox of ssis project, please refer to left pane in the the following documents about Control Flow components and Data Flow components:

- [Control Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137681.aspx)
- [Data Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140080.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't think so. This is a official links, and i'm sure the first two links will never change. Besides, how can i provide the essential parts of the answer? The issue includes many components, I think the links are very helpful.

Comment: Microsoft has broken their own links before. Plenty of times, sadly, without providing redirects